# Buffer with input output shorted

Tags: buffer

[image]

Is there any special purpose of sorting input output of a buffer?

Comment: Try a feedback resistor <10M instead with AC coupled Cap. Then you have a linear HPF amplifier.  Yours has no purpose.  Buffers essential in FF&'s registers used on long lines as the Miller Capacitance can accept a glitch with feedthru to internal input and can toggle the output.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any special purpose of sorting input output of a buffer?

Since the input and output of your buffer are the same net, let's just call this net "B".

Now give the buffer a low output strength (high output impedance).

Connect net B to one or several tristatable higher drive strength outputs.

One of these drivers can output a "1" or a "0", then go tri-state, and your feedback buffer will "remember" the value that was previously output. If several drivers output different values at different times, the buffer will remember the last one.

Not something you'd use every day, but why not?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a few times when I wanted a buffer to give enhanced drive capability but wasn't too sure about how much problematic delay it would introduce. Basically, the buffer became a DNF (do not fit) until such time that I decided a buffer needed to be fitted and the PCB was track cut.

Simply put: leave options open if you can - it might save a PCB iteration.